# Forward Ctrl+C &c. over "ssh -tt" running w/ command from heredoc

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh

I'm trying to have a shell script I can use to do `connect somemachine` to simplify the following pattern

```
ssh somemachine
tmux a
```

I've tried using here docs as [Python subprocess with heredocs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1376016/python-subprocess-with-heredocs) in order to send "tmux a" command

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh $1@$2 << 'ENDSSH'
tmux a
ENDSSH
```

however that fails with "stdin is not a terminal". Following suggestion in [Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7114990/pseudo-terminal-will-not-be-allocated-because-stdin-is-not-a-terminal) I did following modification

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh -tt $1@$2 << 'ENDSSH'
tmux a
ENDSSH
```

But now all my shortcuts are intercepted. IE, CTRL+C will kill my SSH session rather than forwarding SIGINT to the process. Any suggestions?

Comment: "shortcuts" is rather ambiguous language -- it wasn't obvious to me what you meant by the term without clicking through. Hopefully the new title still reflects your intent acceptably?

Comment: Does it work as a oneliner: `ssh somemachine tmux a` ?

Comment: `ssh` accept a last argument with the command to be run in the remote machine. Did you try just `ssh somemachine "tmux a"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just need the `-t` flag and not use the heredoc. Using the heredoc means that the ssh process doesn't have the terminal as its stdin (it has the heredoc instead) so it can't forward it to pseudo-terminal on the remote side. Using the `-tt` flag forces the pts to be allocated without having an input which means that keypresses go to the local process not the remote one.

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh $1@$2 -t tmux a
```

works for me